# Training a Model that Doesn't Always Have All the Features

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, feature-selection, data-imputation

I am creating a model that gathers data from multiple sources and determines a confidence level for an instance that is common across those sources (ie. all sources have different features, but all have a row for 'Foo', 'Bar', etc that I want a confidence level for). The issue is that I will not always have data from all the sources, affecting the number of features I have when running the final trained model.

I have thought about creating a different model for each permutation of data inputs that I have ie. if there are possible inputs from data sources A, B, and C then I would have a model trained for (A, B, C), (A, B), (A, C), and (B, C), but this can quickly become a lot of models.

I also thought to make the features of the data that are not present 0, indicating to the model there should be a lower confidence, but the represented data might actually have 0 values.

Would it be best to go forward with the second approach and manipulate the features, so they will never be 0 values if data is present? I am still unsure of that approach because I will have to train the model with all permutations of data being present.

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of your model? I am confused by the information you have provided.

Comment: My model's goal is to take data from multiple sources that all relate to a common instance (ie. data source 1 gives me features x and y and data source 2 gives me features a and b about the instance), and do a classification. The problem is, sometimes I will have data from some of those sources but not others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three options in this situation:

- First option is to **train separate models** for all the possible combinations. This is a good option in case there are a lot of entries that do not have all the features.
- Second option is to **delete all the samples that do not have all features** and then train the model on the ones that have all features. This is a good choice if there are not a lot of samples with missing data.
- Third option is to **impute the missing values**. It is basically similar to what you have suggested with using `0`, however does not affect the model that much. General practice is to replace the missing values with the *mean/median/mode* of the column.
- There are also more complicated methods to do this, including running a model on the existing features to predict the missing ones. For example, if you have 3 existing features: `A`, `B`, `C`, and one missing feature `X`, you can predict `X` based on the values of `A`, `B` and `C`. You can do this by using [IterativeImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer.html) or [KNNImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html) from the SciKit learn library in Python. The first one uses a regression while the second uses a KNN cluster.

Answer (score 2):

You may impute the missing values, as Nemo_the_scientist has recommended, and to add information to the model, to distinguish the imputed values from the original values, you could add variables that signal that they are imputed with a boolean value.